# The difference between async, async* and sync* in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I know there are `async`, `async*` and `sync*` in Flutter. However, I only know when and how to use `async`, not `async*` and `sync*`.

I know that I need to mark `async` for the function when the function body has `await`, but when to mark `async*` or `sync*`?

What is the difference between these three? Also, when and how to use them? It would be better if you could share some sample code about `async`, `async*` and `sync*`.

Thanks a lot if someone can tell me what the difference is. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the Dart language tour about *Generators*: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generators

In short, `sync*` creates an `Iterable`, and `async*` creates a `Stream`, and both use `yield` to add one element, and `yield*` to splice an existing iterable or stream into the result.

Answer (score 2):

**async**

---

The Future class, part of dart:async, is used for getting the result of a computation after an asynchronous task has completed. This Future value is then used to do something after the computation finishes. Once the read operation is completed, the execution control is transferred within "then()".

**async***

---

Async and Await keywords are used to provide a declarative way to define the asynchronous function and use their results. The async keyword is used when we want to declare a function as asynchronous and the await keyword is used only on asynchronous functions

**sync***

---

In Dart language the synchronous data sequence means the instance of Iterable . The asynchronous data sequence means the instance of Stream . P.S. Generator functions can generate data items indefinitely until the function returns.